# Firebase - how get attribution in android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-ads-api, firebase-analytics

I want to get information about the source in my mobile application. For example, I advertise an application via UAC and I want to know that the user came from there. In other words, I want to get user attribution in a mobile app.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics for Firebase, your most important events are called conversions. Once an event is marked as conversion, Google Analytics for Firebase will associate the campaign details (source, medium, campaign name, etc.) to this event.

Conversions shows how many conversion events were driven by each aspect of your marketing (e.g., campaign, ad network, creative).

See this documentation for your [reference](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en).

Comment: I am interested in information on how to get attribution in the application, not in the console.

Comment: I get it, you are suggesting that I connect postbacks that will send attribution?

Comment: It depends on the Ad Network that you will be using. For example, Google Ads. Once you link Google Ads with Firebase and you launch a campaign, then that campaign causes the user to trigger conversion events. The details of that campaign will be automatically attributed to the conversion event.